# How do I get a form to stop after a curtain amount of charackters?

Tags: javascript

So I got this code, but i cant figure out how to make it stop after a curtain amout of charackers, how can I do that? Thanks in advance for any answers!.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hover</title>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-
1.8.1.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Keyup</h1>
<hr>
<form action="#">
<textarea rows="10" cols="20" id="message" name="message">
</textarea>
<p>Characters remaining: <span id="remaining">50</span></p>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 var maxCharacters = 50;
 $("#message").on("keyup", function(){
  var currentVal = $("#message").val().length;
  var totalRemaining = maxCharacters - currentVal;
  $("#remaining").text(totalRemaining);
 });
});
 
 
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a8yepy1u/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var maxCharacters = 50;
    $("#message").on("keyup keydown", function(event){
        var currentVal = $("#message").val().length;
        var totalRemaining = maxCharacters - currentVal;
        if(+$(this).val().length >= maxCharacters)
            event.preventDefault(); // stop the default action of the event
        $("#remaining").text(totalRemaining);
    });
});
```

Hope it helps ...

Answer (score 1):

the quickest solution (without any js coding), will be to set maxlength.

```
<textarea maxlength="50" rows="10" cols="20" id="message" name="message"></textarea>
```

Comment: I think maxlength in texarea is a browser feature and not a standrad

Answer (score 0):

this is how you black the input:

```
   $("#message").attr("disabled");
```

you need to add this code to a listener, either inside your keyup function or on your

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var maxCharacters = 50;
    $("#message").on("keyup", function(){
        var currentVal = $("#message").val().slice(0, maxCharacters);
        $("#message").val(currentVal);
        var totalRemaining = maxCharacters - currentVal.length;
        $("#remaining").text(totalRemaining); 
    });
});
```